# Title Tooltip Spacing Issue

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have used `padEnd` for equal space for the string and binding in the title. When I console the string. The string is perfectly aligned with spaced but the binded title looks different. Do the title supports the spacing?

Code

```
arr = [{ name: "Rasagula", carbs: 16.6 },{ name: "Masala Vada", carbs: 16.2 },{ name: "Veg Bonda", carbs: 8.1 }];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.manipulateArr();
  }
  manipulateArr() {
    var carbs = this.arr.map(k => k.carbs);
    var items = this.arr.map(k => k.name);
    this.printThis = items.map((x, i) => {
    this.spacePad(x) + " : " + carbs[i] + "(g)";
    }).join('/n');
  }
  spacePad(value) {
    return value.padEnd(25);
  }
```

HTML

```
<td title={{printThis}}>Some Values</td>
```

**Console**

[image]

**My View**

[image]

Comment: You have to use a monospace font

Comment: Can you explain in detail so that I can accept that answer. Thanks

Comment: Also please, bind using the correct syntax: `[title]="myVariable"`

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip is generated based on the `title` attribute, but it's rendered by your OS, and it uses a different font-family than your web page. It seems that it's not a monospaced font, which means the widths of the letters are not equal. However a browser's console mostly use monospaced font, that's why it appears aligned there, but not in the tooltip. Sadly you can't style the tooltip, but you can use a tooltip library that let's you doing this by rendering the text inside your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The font used in the console is a monospace font, which means that each character have the exact same width, by default the web browser does not use a monospace font.

In order to force a monospace font you can use this CSS rule :

`font-family: monospace;`

You will have to create your own tooltip.

```
#trigger-tooltip {
 position: relative;
}
#trigger-tooltip:hover #tooltip {
 font-family: monospace;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: but how use specify `title` in css

Comment: Oh, my bad, you can't style a native tooltip, you will have to create your own tooltip.

Comment: @Felix Christo i added more info

Comment: Tq. Will workout and let you know. Should I create something in html part?

Comment: Yes of course, there has to be 2 html elements, one being the trigger and the other one being the tooltip.

Comment: I have used in `<td>`. After implementing this. My values gone invisible

Comment: Put the tooltip element inside the original td.

Comment: You should use a library for this. A specific one like `ngx-tooltip`, or some component library that has this feaure, like `@angular/material` or `ngx-bootstrap`.

Comment: @Totati absolutely not. You can't do this with material and it's a 3 liner.

Comment: @Ploppy I absolutely am. [ I'm fabulous](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-multiline-tooltip)

Comment: Of course I'm not :) but I have some experience, I know how to mold a things.

Comment: I know you can, and I know you are fabulous  I just try to not override third party libraries because I usually end up running into breaking changes after a few years of use.

Comment: Yes, it's true, it can cause breaking change, but just a css one. That can happen easily. However we don't test - that's a reason I'm not fabulous - :/ so I prefer a little hack in a third party library than do it all over again.

Answer (score 0):

try with limited character

```
spacePad(value) {
    return value.substr(0, 19).padEnd(25);
  }
```